# How to say the period of time when you are not on vacation?

Tags: phrase-request

Let say I jogged when I was on vacation, would you say that I jogged in that time when I was on vacation? And how to say when I am not on vacation? Would I say in times apart from vacation? They sound strange so please correct as many mistakes as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would not use a qualifier for non-vacation time.

> I like jogging
>
> I go jogging every week
>
> I often go jogging

I would automatically think this means non-vacation time.

If you jog on vacation, you would say:

> I like jogging on vacation
>
> When I go on vacation I often go jogging
>
> While I was on vacation I went jogging every week.

If you wanted to be explicit that you only jog when you are not on holiday, you could say:

> When I'm not on vacation, I go jogging.

But there is no specific word for time when you are not on vacation.